# reset index value to self if greater than a certain numbers

Tags: jquery, arrays, html, indexing, html5-video

I've been struggling with an array and its increments, but I think I have a solution.  Maybe.  The problem is that when a video ends in the array, it adds an increment to the play video function I've employed.  This wouldn't be a problem, except it keeps adding up if you're clicking through the videos.

I realized that I should be able to reset the index value, whatever it is and regardless of how many times I've clicked, to the index value of the video when I click.  Then, when the video ends, boom, increment is `$("#myVid").index()`+1.

I just need to know how to write this. I've tried just having `index= $("#myVid").index()` under the onclick, but that doesn't work. I've also tried wrapping it in an if function (which seems like overkill), like so:

```
if (index >= $("#myVid").index()) {
    index= $("#myVid").index()
}
```

So, how do I set the index value to the value of the video that's playing?  And, no `index = $(this).index();` does not work because all it does is restate the current index value at the beginning of the `click`'s function.

I'll be grateful for any input~

EDIT: per request, the full function and html... so, the html is

```
  <div id="wrapper"><div id="MyT"></div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div id="content">
          <div class="control">
          <div class="progress"><span class="timeBar"></span></div></div>
            <div class="slider"></div>
            <ul class='thumbs'>
                <li rel='1'><div style="top:0px;"><img src="graphics/filler.png" alt="" width="280" height="128" /></div></li>
                <li rel='2'><div style="top:128px;"><img src="graphics/filler2.png" alt="" width="280" height="128" /></div></li>
                <li rel='3'><div style="top:256px;"><img src="graphics/filler.png" alt="" width="280" height="128" /></div></li>
                <li rel='4'><div style="top:384px;"><img src="graphics/filler2.png" alt="" width="280" height="128" /></div></li>
                <li rel='5'><div style="top:512px;"><img src="graphics/filler.png" alt="" width="280" height="128" /></div></li>
                <li rel='6'><div style="top:640px;"><img src="graphics/filler2.png" alt="" width="280" height="128" /></div></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
<div id="bigPic">
 <video id="myVid" alt="" class="normal" type="m4v" showlogo="false" height="768" width="1024"/>
</div>
```

and then the related, full, functions
for the click

```
$('li', '.thumbs').on('touchstart click', function() {
    index = $(this).index();
    var myVideo = document.getElementById('myVid');
        myVideo.src = videos[index];
        myVideo.load();
        myVideo.play();
        if (index >= $("#myVid").index()) {
            index= $("#myVid").index()
                }
```

and then for the play next

```
 $("#myVid").bind("ended", function() {
            $("#bigPic").removeClass("move");
            $("#MyT").fadeIn(250);
            function playArray(ele, array) {
                if (index   >= array.length) {
                    index = 1;
                }
                if ($("#myVid").index() < index+1) {
                    index++;    
                }

                ele.src = array[index];
                ele.load();
                ele.play();
            }
            playArray(document.getElementById("myVid"), videos);
        });
    });
```

Edit: okay, a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nata2ha/Tr7K9/) here, with all of the functions

Comment: Can you post HTML as well please? And probably your full jQuery function. Also, as a side note, as `#myVid` is an ID, meaning, there can only be one of them, the index in the situation described above will never change. (Unless of course you're modifying the DOM - but I don't think you are).

Comment: What do you think *$("#myVid").index()* does?

Comment: @dbaseman get the current index value of ("#myVid"). And it worked for another part, either beca=use of a fluke or luck. What it needs to do is get the index value of the video that is playing... and  this was kind of dumped on me, and I'm not experienced enough with using arrays....

Comment: `$("#myVid").index()` will return the index of the "myVid" element in relation to its siblings. This value will always be the same because it doesn't have any siblings, and you're not dynamically adding or removing elements. This has nothing at all to do with which video is or was playing.

Comment: @nnnnnn okay, didn't know that... how can I get the value for the video thats playing then, since its not by `$("#myVid").index()`?

Comment: I don't understand your explanation of why setting `index` in the click handler doesn't work. Are you saying that if you click a link when there is already a video playing that causes the new video to start playing, setting `index` to the new video, but then the "ended" event occurs for the video that was playing and that changes `index` too?

Comment: @nnnnnn no, it's that if you click a few times, the index increases in increments, but the `index` set in the click handler doesn't set it back to the index value of the playing video, but for some reason only redeclares what the index (which at this point it some odd number) is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a complete solution, because I don't really understand your explanation of the problem, but...

Your use of the jQuery [`.index()` method](http://api.jquery.com/index/) with `$("#myVid").index()` is not an appropriate way to figure out the current video's index since it will always just return the index of the "myVid" element relative to its siblings (which won't ever change). You have used `.index()` correctly within the "li" click handler, since (as far as I can tell) you actually want the index relative to siblings in that case, to tell you which one was clicked.

I think it would help you a lot if you tidied up your code. Don't repeat the code that sets the video source and loads and plays it - move that stuff into a single function, and then call that function from the different places that need it:

```
var videos = [ /* your array of videos, you don't
                  show how this is defined */ ],
    currentVideo;

function playVideo(videoNumToPlay) {
   var myVideo = document.getElementById('myVid');
   myVideo.src = videos[videoNumToPlay];
   myVideo.load();
   myVideo.play();
   currentVideo = videoNumToPlay;
}

$('li', '.thumbs').on('touchstart click', function() {
    playVideo( $(this).index() );
});

$("#myVid").bind("ended", function() {
   $("#bigPic").removeClass("move");
   $("#MyT").fadeIn(250);       
   playVideo( (currentVideo + 1) % videos.length );
});
```

I don't see how the above would go wrong, because now the only place in the code that starts a video playing is within the new `playVideo()` function, and that function takes a parameter `videoNumToPlay` for which video to play and saves that number in `currentVideo` so within the "ended" handler we can use `currentVideo` to figure out the index one higher (wrapping around to the beginning of the array as needed).

If you also need to set some classes to highlight the li corresponding to the currently playing video or something I'd do that from with the `playVideo()` function. (You've obviously got additional code that you're not showing, but I can't guess exactly what you're doing in that other code.)

Comment: it doesn't play the one, just loops the current( and the next together), although it's better because it actually plays the next video... I did put the entirety of the function in a fiddle....

Comment: This helped. I made a new function (`playVideo2`), and used that onclick. on end, though, I used `playVideo( (currentVideo + 1) % videos.length );`, and it did the trick. I wasn't aware of that method to play the next video, and now it works, so than you!